# How do I transport data from 1 class to another in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a `Connect` button and a `Disconnect` button in `main.py`.

The `Connect` button is enabled and the `Disconnect` button is disabled. When I click on the `Connect` button, a lambda expression is called that will toggle the device connection (`toggle_device_connection`) in another class `Modbus` in another file `modbus.py`. I have another lambda expression right after it that will disable the Connect button and enable the `Disconnect` button and visa versa (`toggle_buttons`).

The problem is that whenever the connection in the 1st lambda expressions raises an exception (like the connection was unsuccesful), it will still toggle the button from enabled to disabled, which is not desired.

Example code:

```py
modbus = modbus class

connect_button = Button(parent, text='Connect', command= lambda: (modbus.toggle_device_connection(state=1),
                                                                  toggle_buttons(state=1)))
disconnect_button = Button(parent, text='Disconnect', command= lambda: (modbus.toggle_device_connection(state=0),
                                                                        toggle_buttons(state=0)))
```

The question is: How do I transport data from 1 class to another? (in this particular example)

**ANSWER**

I think my answer is the following:

```py
# Main.py
self.modbus = Modbus()

connect_button = Button(parent, text='Connect', command= lambda: modbus.toggle_device_connection(state=True)

def toggle_buttons(self, state=False):
    if state:
        # Disable Connect
        # Enable Disconnect
    else:
        # Enable Connect
        # Disable Disconnect

self.modbus.device_connection = lambda bool: toggle_buttons(state=bool)

# Modbus.py
self.device_connection = lambda bool: 'Connection unsuccessful'

def toggle_device_connection(self):
    ...
    if success:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    ...
```

Comment: You can try adding a try except block and in the except change the states of the buttons to the desired ones.

Comment: I don't know how to use the return value of a lambda expression to use it in the toggle_buttons functio (If that is even possible)

Comment: The return value of callbacks is lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit more code, but you could use `tk.BooleanVar`, with a `trace_add` that listens to a change of value of the variable, and a mechanism to toggle the button state depending on the success/failure of the connection:

Maybe something like this:

```
import random
import tkinter as tk


def connection():
    # has no knowledge of your GUI
    conn = random.choice([False, True, True])   # simulate a network failure 1/3rd of the tim
    status = 'successful' if conn else 'fail'
    print(f'connected {status}')
    return conn   # not a callback, so the return value can be used

def connect_callback():
    print('...connecting')
    # use the return value to alter the connection_status
    # maybe defend it in a try / except block
    connection_status.set(connection())

def disconnect_callback():
    print('...disconnecting')
    connection_status.set(False)

def set_buttons_aspect(*args):
    if connection_status.get():
        btn1.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
        btn2.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
    else:
        btn1.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
        btn2.config(state=tk.DISABLED)        


root = tk.Tk()

connection_status = tk.BooleanVar(root)
connection_status.set(False)

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text='connect', command=connect_callback)
btn1.pack()
btn2 = tk.Button(root, text='disconnect', command=disconnect_callback)
btn2.pack()
set_buttons_aspect()

connection_status.trace_add('write', set_buttons_aspect)  
# listens to changes in connection_status and calls set_buttons_aspect when it occurs

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a function.

... lambda:function(params)...

And do the function

function(params):
    try:
       ... 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        do_something()